# Necessity of prefixing all PHP pages with ob_start() 

Tags: php, output-buffering

Is it OK to have `ob_start()` in the beginning of all PHP pages?

If I don't do this, I get the "headers already sent" error.

Comment: If those errors are being raised against your intention you may want to check for loose/premature output and stuff first.

Comment: yup, remember to `open_end_clean` it `ob_end_flush`
but u should look for where the header come from

Comment: @ajreal - I'm pretty sure you meant `ob_end_clean`, not `open_end_clean`. :)

Comment: @Matt Huggins - soli, is 3am now ...

Comment: +1 to compensate for the downvote (why btw?) and because this is actually a nice topic about general application style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "ok" but you should really fix your script to not output stuff prematurely and save the output for the end. But you can just change a setting in `.htaccess` or the `php.ini` the below is the for .htaccess:

```
php_value output_buffering On
php_value output_handler mb_output_handler
```

This would be preferred, in my opinion, instead of adding `ob_start` to the top of all your scripts.

However, you really should fix the problem at its core. IE: Save output for the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

you may have **white space before    at the top of page**

This will lead that error "HEADER ALREADY SEND "

No idea about ob_start()

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is okay to do this as a workaround or when simply quickly making your existing script work. In the long run however you should think about redesigning your application so things like this don't happen. In general you should try to completely separate application logic and the output.